# Макрос и операционная система (си)

Tags: linux, c, windows, макрос

Хочу написать условие для компиляции кода в виндоус 32 и 64. Вроде этого

```
#ifdef linux
    #Include <curses.h>
#else
   #include <conio.h>
#endif
```

Какие наименования у макросов для виндовс32 и 64?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672887/is-there-a-define-for-64-bit-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: В стандартном языке С нет никаких "макросов для виндовс32 и 64". Наличие и наименование подобных макросов зависит от компилятора. О каких компиляторах идет речь?

Comment: Компиляторы clang и gcc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Здесь](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system) перечислены макросы, которые определяются для разных платформ различными компиляторами. Так, для различения платформ win32/win64/linux попробуйте такой код (проверен мной для GCC и Clang на платформе GNU/Linux):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
#if defined(_WIN64)
    printf("Win64");
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    printf("Win32");
#elif defined(linux)
    printf("GNU/Linux");
#else
    printf("Unknown");
#endif
    printf(" platform detected.\n");
}
```

**Update.**
Важно отметить, что символ _WIN32 определён и для 32-битной, и для 64-битной Windows, а _WIN64 - только для 64-битной. Поэтому сначала проверяется _WIN64, и это имеет значение!

Comment: @0xdb Странно. У меня [открывается](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system). На всякий убрал под якорь в посте.

Comment: В порядке, рабочий ноут блокировал.